# getting min-width and min device width to work at the same time

Tags: responsive-design, width, media-queries

This works on my iphone

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
```

This works in chrome

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 320px) 
and (max-width : 480px) {
```

Can I get them working both on the same set of rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with just max-width and min-width in your queries unless you want specific small-device styles. Make sure you are using a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` to get those queries to apply on small screen devices. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">`